# How to return an async/await promise in a Mongoose virtual field

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

In my NodeJS application I'm using a virtual field (with Mongoose) which adds a rating field to my 'Club' model. The value of this rating is coming from Facebook ([facebook-node-sdk](https://github.com/node-facebook/facebook-node-sdk)). I'm currently having the following code:

```
async function getFbRating(slug) {
   var ratingPromise = await FB.api(slug, { fields: 'overall_star_rating' });
   var rating = ratingPromise.overall_star_rating;
   console.log('1: ' + rating);
   return rating;
};

clubSchema.virtual('rating').get(async function() {
   const ratingPromise = getFbRating(this.fb);
   const rating = await ratingPromise;
   console.log('2: ' + rating);
   return rating;
});
```

This code is logging the correct ratings..

```
1: 3.8
2: 3.8
```

But the 'rating' field is not returning any value

```
rating: {}
```

Now I did some research and found out that a virtual field cannot return a promise, which explains the empty return. I also read things about using a Mongoose method instead, but I cannot figure out how..

Currently, I'm totally lost on how I can save this value to my database. Hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: Just like is said on [Issues#184](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1894) *"Use a custom method instead"*. This type of call to an external API really has nothing to do with "schema". Instead it's a method implementation, and probably best done as outlined in ["Advanced Schemas"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/advanced_schemas.html) where it talks about loading an existing class. Don't ask for the "schema" to serialize this because it will not. Instead make your "class" serialize and wrap the schema serialization with the additional output of custom methods.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @NeilLunn !